# How make SelectList use ToString() method for displaying elements and set dataValueField atribute at the same time

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

There are 4 overloads for `SelectList`. I want to display elements in `DropDownList` as concatenation of properties inside them(exacly as result `ToString()` method) and remember their id in `dataValueField`.

If I use **:**

1. `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CallsToMake, new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake.OrderByDescending(call => call.TimeStamp)))`

I will get `DropDownList` which' elements are presented by result of `ToString()` method which is good, but I didn't pass: `dataValueField` attribute(I want it to be the `Id`).

The `ToString()` method looks like:

```
public override string ToString() {
            return Caller.UserName + " called at " + TimeStamp;
    }
```

OR

2. `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CallsToMake, new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake.OrderByDescending(call => call.TimeStamp), "Id", "TimeStamp"))`

Here I passed `Id` to `dataValueField` parameter but `dataTextField` was initilized by `TimeStamp` I would like get result of `ToString()` here so `DropDownList` will be readable for user.

The `CallToMake` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class CallToMake {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Callee { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Caller { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
                return Caller.UserName + " called at " + TimeStamp;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

Mardoxx's solution shows adding property but I am affraid that Entity Framework will add this property to the table and store all data once again in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer is freakingly easy. Just pass `null` as dataTextField and it will use `ToString()`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CallsToMake, new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake.OrderByDescending(call => call.TimeStamp), "Id", null), new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", style = "width: 500px;" })
```

Microsoft's documentation shows lack here.

Comment: Can't believe that this hasn't been marked as the answer or voted up more.

Comment: @sgrassie Thank you very much for appreciation, I probably was feeling  rude to accept my own answer before receiving any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below property to `CallToMake`

```
public String StringVal { get { return Caller.UserName + " called at " + TimeStamp; } set; }
```

then use the below in your html

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CallsToMake, new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake.OrderByDescending(call => call.TimeStamp), "Id", "StringVal"))
```

(or make `StringVal`'s getter return `this.ToString()` if you're using the overridden `ToString()` function elsewhere)

Comment: Will then the property will be stored by Entity Framework in the database, therefore store redundant data(double the size of record)?

Comment: Good question, I do not know. I would be tempted to make a new function on your model that returned a `SelectList` with the correctly formatted data.

Comment: It will add this property to the database it should so it shouldn't be done this way. But how to make this additional method in model, what more can be done inside model than in Razor view here? Please show how to create such function.